# Compare two arrays to fetch more data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement

I want compare two arrays, and when they have the same elements in the array I want to output it and if they are not the same then don't output it.

It's something like a quiz, so I have two arrays with numbers, first is number of rows in the table and second is random numbers and I want an `if(???)` to create quiz from array number 2 (I tried `array_intersect` etc, but it doesn't work).

So i fetch data from the database and i only want data with `id` same as numbers in array2 (id are in array1)

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$array2 = array(5,3,2);

$number = 0;
echo "<form method='post' action='xxx.php'>";
while ($qt = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
if(???){
//Data processing
  }
}
echo "<input type='submit'>
</form>";
```

Comment: Do you have a Query written for retrieving rows from the database?

Comment: yes i have, but why you want it (sorry for edit)

Comment: I believe you're trying to create quiz based on random ids, right? Please post your SQL query and the *relevant* PHP code as well. Also, if a *random* quiz is your requirement, then you don't need those two hardcoded arrays, you can do everything in just one simple query, `SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3`

Comment: `$a = "SELECT * FROM test";$data = mysqli_query($connect, $a);` and if i use `ran(id)` so I always get the same thing

Comment: Could you please explain the logic/motivation behind this code i.e. what exactly you're trying to accomplish as an end result? Also, you didn't answer my question, are you trying to build a random quiz comprising of 3 random questions from your table?

Comment: So i fetch data from the database from table test and i only want data with id same as numbers in array2 (id are in array1), yes i build a random quiz comprising of 3 random questions from my table

Comment: @Dolis I've given an answer below, hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [**OP's comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533318/compare-two-arrays-to-fetch-more-data#comment70272706_41533318),

> So i fetch data from the database from table test and i only want data with id same as numbers in array2 (id are in array1), yes i build a random quiz comprising of 3 random questions from my table

You don't need those arrays. If your sole purpose is to build a quiz comprising of 3 random questions from the table, then construct your query and the subsequent code like this:

```
$a = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";
$data = mysqli_query($connect, $a);

while($qt = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
    // your code
}
```

Comment: oukey thank you so much, I was stupid I make things unnecessarily complicated

Comment: @Dolis Glad I could help. *Cheers! ;-)*